# No CPU integrated graphics. How can I get graphics in Hyper-v without losing host GPU video?

Tags: hyper-v-manager

I have a Windows 7 Pro SP1 Hyper-v Gen 2 VM on my host Windows 11 Pro. I want to use the VM for old games, but my CPU has no video h/w (Intel 9700K). If I use DDA to attach my GPU to the VM, I would have no video at all for my host. Is there another way to support my Win 7 graphics? I DO have 2 monitors on the GPU. Can I just attach one of them or do I have to attach the entire GPU? Remote-FX is no longer available.

Comment: Buy another graphics card.